# How to select the second record if have 2 records, and if have one then select just that one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one query that may return 1 or 2 records. I want to select the second record if the query returns 2, otherwise just select 1. How can I do it?

Comment: `TOP 1` and an `ORDER BY`??? You've given us very little to work with here; I suggest one sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 2):

"second" means that you have an ordering in mind -- because results sets represent unordered sets, unless there is an explicit ordering  Just reverse the ordering and choose the top record:

```
select top (1) q.*
from (<your query here>) q
order by ? desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data and expected results would help. When you do supply this, it will help qualify how you intend to select the second row i.e. based on what?

In the absence of sample data, here's a quick example to show a way of tackling this.

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE MixedMartialArts;
GO
USE MixedMartialArts;
GO
CREATE SCHEMA mma;
GO
CREATE TABLE mma.Team (
    Id int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    TeamName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Country nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
);
GO
CREATE TABLE mma.Fighter (
    Id int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    TeamId int NOT NULL,
    FighterName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Country nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Reputation int NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (TeamId) REFERENCES mma.Team(Id)
);
GO
INSERT INTO mma.Team
    (TeamName,Country)
VALUES
    ('American Kickboxing Academy','USA'),
    ('Nova União','Brazil'),
    ('Straight Blast Gym','Ireland'),
    ('London Shootfighters','England');
GO
INSERT INTO mma.Fighter
    (TeamId, FighterName, Country, Reputation)
VALUES
    (1,'Daniel Cormier','USA',9),
    (1,'Khabib Nurmagomedov','Russia',8),
    (2,'Jose Aldo Jr.','Brazil',8),
    (3,'Conor McGregor','Ireland',9),
    (4,'Kay Em Em','England',10)
;
GO
-- 1. Query that may return 1 or 2 rows.
SELECT              t.TeamName,
                    f.FighterName
FROM                mma.Team t
    INNER JOIN      mma.Fighter f ON t.Id = f.TeamId;
GO
```

[results of query 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWWuB.png)

```
-- 2. For the query that may return 1 or 2 rows, you want to return the second row if the query returns 2 rows, otherwise just select 1 row.
WITH FighterTeam AS (
    SELECT          t.TeamName,
                    f.FighterName,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.TeamId ORDER BY f.Reputation ASC) AS RowNum
    FROM            mma.Fighter f
        INNER JOIN  mma.Team t ON f.TeamId = t.Id
), FighterTeamGrouping AS (
    SELECT          TeamName,
                    COUNT(RowNum) AS Total
    FROM            FighterTeam
    GROUP BY        TeamName
)
SELECT              ft.TeamName,
                    ft.FighterName
FROM                FighterTeam ft
    INNER JOIN      FighterTeamGrouping ftg ON ft.TeamName = ftg.TeamName
WHERE               ft.RowNum = CASE WHEN ftg.Total = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```

[results of query 2 showing removal of "second row"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F3JT.png)